# "My shares were valued 1M USD at that moment" or "My share was valued 1M USD at that moment"?

Tags: word-choice

Just wondering which one is correct.

Should I say `share` or `shares`?

Updated on Jan 19: **Yes, I mean the ownership of a company**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is frequently the case, it depends on what you mean.

Prices are ratios and, in the US, denominated in dollars per unit. In the case of shares of stock, the commonly used unit is one share of stock.

> Stock X is worth 1000 dollars per share.

In contexts, however, where it is clear that what is being discussed are prices, the unit may be implicitly assumed rather than explicitly mentioned.

> Stock Y jumped from 3 dollars to 8 dollars in two weeks

means

> The price per share of stock Y jumped from 3 dollars to 8 dollars in two weeks.

If you are talking about the aggregate market value of more than one share, then you would definitely use the plural "shares" (or the collective nouns "holding" or "portfolio")

> The value of my shares in company Z is one million dollars

means

> The value of my holding in company Z is one million dollars.

In short, when talking about price, you will avoid confusion and be perfectly idiomatic by using "the price is p dollars per share." If you are talking about the aggregate market value of a set of shares, use "the aggregate value of the shares is q dollars."

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about shares in multiple businesses then it's "shares" if it's just the one business then "share" is fine, even if it actually referred to multiple individual "shares" although it would be a somewhat uncommon usage unless you had already been talking about the equity in percentage terms e.g. "I owned 40% of the business, my share was valued at 1M USD" and even then it's still more common to encounter "shares".

Of course if what you're talking about is not shares in a company (e.g. it's talking about partial ownership of another asset or collection of assets such as a house or a deceased relative's estate)  then it would **always** be "share"